# MEAN app crashed on Internet disconnection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am developing a MEAN application. When I use localhost for local development the app is running fine on http://localhost:3300 when Internet is there but throws below error when the Internet is disconnected.

```
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:49:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can anyone help me resolving this strange issue? As app is on localhost,it should not have any dependency on Internet.
My MongoDB connection is on mongodb://localhost:27017.

Thanks!

Comment: You actually "mean" that you disabled your network adapter, and that you are running on Windows. That happens.

Comment: Yes @BlakesSeven . I am running on windows 8.1. When the wi-fi is disconnected this is happening!

Comment: When you disable a network adapter on Windows all netwoking is reset. I'ts a know issue. However you can re-enable services after you disable it. Or in the very simple case, "do not hard disable" the adapter. Just let the Wi-fi connection go away by itself. Anyhow, not a programming question. Ask you computer network configuration questions on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing all `localhost` occurrences with `127.0.0.1`  
Had the same problem. Turns out without an active internet connection `localhost` cannot be resolved into a valid IP.

Answer (score 0):

**Make your own local network.**

I don't know the exact reason why this is happening. But I noticed that if your pc is not assigned an IP address it will produce this error.

So what I did was, **I turned my portable wifi hotspot on and re-run the app and whoa! It worked!** That hotspot assigned an IP address to my pc. So, it simply means you should be connected to any network. It can be your mobile hotspot too.